# Remove the Chapter number, but keep chapter number in the formula

Tags: sectioning, equations, numbering, chapters

I have a problem just as the following picture. I want to remove the chapter number in appendix, but keep the number in the formula. I have tried many times.

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a KOMA-Script class like `scrbook` or `scrreprt` you can redefine `\chapterformat` (and `\chaptermarkformat` and `\thesection`) inside `\appendix`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\apptocmd\appendix{\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{}\let\chaptermarkformat\chapterformat\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}}{}{}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
\appendix
\chapter{Anhang}
\section{Lange Formeln}
\begin{equation}
  f(x)=a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i+j+k+l+m
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

But have a look at: »[Wie setzt man korrekt einen Anhang?](http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/19227/wie-setzt-man-korrekt-einen-anhang)« (in German, but it seems the OP does understand German).